# MySQL count percentual of occurrences greater than

Tags: mysql, group-by, average, conditional-aggregation

I have a table like this.

```
+  day +  person + amount +
+------+---------+--------+
+    1 +    John +      4 +
+------+---------+--------+
+    1 +     Sam +      6 +
+------+---------+--------+
+    2 +    John +      3 +
+------+---------+--------+
+    3 +    John +      3 +
+------+---------+--------+
+    3 +     Sam +      5 +
+------+---------+--------+
+    4 +    John +      3 +
+------+---------+--------+
```

How can I get a percentual of entries where the amount is greater than 3 (or other) grouped by people?
I want my output to be: John 25%, Sam 100%.
When the clause is "amount greater than 5", I would have: John 0%, Sam 50%.
It would be nice to minimize the overload when table becomes big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AVG()` aggregate function with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT person,
       100 * AVG(amount > ?) percent
FROM tablename
GROUP BY person;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/sU1Oj1Pg).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT person, 100 * SUM(amount > @criteria) / COUNT(*) needed_percent
FROM src_table
GROUP BY person
```

where `@criteria` is needed amount value (3, 5, etc.).